# What are these lights above the panel in a Blue Angels cockpit?

Tags: flight-instruments, cockpit, aerobatics

I found the following picture on the Blue Angels Facebook page:

[image: US Navy Blue Angels F/A-18 cockpit]

What is the purpose of the lights over the pilot's panel? (The two on the top are green)

Comment: It looks like an angle of attack indicator.  One for each wing, green amber and red.  I guess it's so that you can see it easily in peripheral vision without looking in.  I can't find any reference.  We need @RhinoDriver

Comment: @Simon If I understood you correctly, the two green-shining lights at the top are AoA-Indicators for the left and the right wing. Correct? Then what do the four lights at the bottom do?

Comment: <Guess>Two green lights, left wing AoA OK, right wing AoA OK.  Two amber lights, left and right wing approaching stall or some critical angle.  Two red lights, stalled.</Guess>

Comment: @Simon Unfortunately still doesn't answer for what the four lights at the bottom are used :/

Comment: Yes it does - the two at the top are green, the four at the bottom are 2x amber, 2x red (one amber for each wing, one red for each wing)

Comment: @Simon Now I understand. If you are completly sure, please add this as an answer.

Comment: I am not completely sure and my Google foo, usually very strong, has deserted me on this one. I've seen a similar indicator fitted to Phantoms (F4s) on a training squadron but that only had 3 lights. It did not distinguish between left and right.  This is fine for fighters who rarely do "aerobatics" but for the Blue Angels , who spend a lot of time on the edge of the control envelope, it makes sense. From what I can find, it's not standard fit on F18s so my guess (again) is that it's a Blue Angels specific mod.

Comment: @Simon I agree with you, thank you. I know for the swiss air force F/A-18, they don't have this build in.

Comment: I'm finding it a little weird why to give 6 mutually exclusive lights of "on[color]/off" when 2 of variable color would suffice. Especially in such obtrusive location limiting field of view.

Comment: @Simon I'm pretty sure it's not AoA - I haven't ever heard of it being displayed per wing, and that's a lot of device for something that they'd also have displayed on their HUD.

Comment: I did say guess work, but is does seem similar to an [indicator like this](http://wiki.hoggit.us/images/thumb/6/67/AoA_Indexer.jpg/200px-AoA_Indexer.jpg) which in turn is very similar to one that was fitted on Phantom FGR2s on a conversion unit.

Comment: @Simon This is the Angle of Attack Indicator. See the answer below, they are placed on the left side of the HUD.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not absolutely sure but I think they are the indicators for the inverted fuel pump. From [arcforums](http://www.arcforums.com/forums/air/index.php?showtopic=133297&st=0):

> I finally spoke to a friend of mine who used to fly with the Blue Angels during the 2000/2001 show season. He said the lights on the glare shield were for the inverted pump indicator. The BA fly inverted longer than what is normally permitted for the Hornet so the Blue Angels aircraft are modified with a boost pump mounted to the top of the fuel tank. When they fly an inverted manuver for an extended period that pump is truned on, and while inverted fuel is pumped from the main tank to the feed tank. As fuel in the feed tanks is burned, the light would turns from green to yellow to red. When the light turns red it's time to roll back to a normal flight attitude.

So the three sets of lights should be for the tanks on both the wings.

I think this is the answer because the angle of attack indexers are found to the left of the HUD and look like this:

[image]

Also, it appears that they (aoa indexers) are found in carrier aircraft (for e.g. A-4 Skyhawk) as approaches are flown at a specified angle of attack rather than at particular airspeeds.

I believe that these lights are Blue angel specific mod as I'm not able to find them in any other versions.

Comment: I think you're right, and they may also include smoke monitoring. There's a simulation mod group that flies as Virtual Blue Angels in the LOMAC engine, and they've [built a replica cockpit](http://forums.eagle.ru/showthread.php?t=77169). There's no print; the lights are certainly not amber, but white, green, and red; there's a separate AoA gauge pasted to the left of the HUD; and they mention BA specific hacks like *Inverted fuel system lights* and *Smoke lights*; ARM and SMOKE is marked on the left set.

Comment: @egid At first I thought the were for smoke monitoring. However, there is only one smoke generator (on the left nozzle if I remember correctly), so I discounted that. Also I think (again guessing) that the smoke indicator is on the left of glare shield.

Answer (score 4):

Right side of the HUD:
Top row of 2 lights on the right side is showing the inverted fuel system is armed.  Below that are the failure lights for that system.  To the right of that is when the inverted fuel pump system is active (for the Double Farvel).

Left side of the HUD:
Left side is a smoke button that arms the smoke system.  Then to the left is a smoke on indicator, and the far right is the inverted fuel pumps switch that turns that system on/off.

The lights have NOTHING to do with AOA.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! The [tour] might be helpful if you're new to the site.